# Gitlab pipeline badge unknown when run pipeline rule is `merge_request_event`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, badge

Facing issue while adding pipeline status badge in my gitlab repository.
It works fine when the run pipeline workflow rule is `push` but due to the gitlab runner constraints need to keep the rule to `merge_request_event`.

But in this case the pipeline status badge not able to show the actual pipeline status.
It shows `unknown`.

**Badge Configuration:**

**Link:** `../%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/coverage.svg`

**Badge image URL:** `../%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/coverage.svg?ignore_skipped=true`

**Output:**

[image]

Tried to look into this issue, and found that gitlab pipeline badge doesn't work with `merge_reqest_event` rule, they has a open ticket created 3 years ago : [Ticket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215530#note_922834954)

If someone can **provide any workaround** will be very helpful.